# Programmatically determining Ubuntu distribution and architecture?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

What's the best way to programmatically determine if the current machine is running Ubuntu, what architecture it has, and what version of Ubuntu it is running?

One way would be to scan the output of `uname -a` to check for the right kernel version and architecture.

Another way would be to scan `/etc/apt/sources.list` for the Ubuntu distribution keyword (eq `precise`, `quantal`, etc)

Is there a better way?

Comment: /etc/lsb-release may have a clue

Answer (score 4):

Apart from  `uname -a`, There are several way to get information about the current distribution.

1. The best way is to parse the release files. They usually ended with `-release` or `_release` and located in `/etc`. Following command will find them all.

   ```
   ls /etc/*{-,_}release
   ```

   - Ubuntu uses `lsb_release`
   - Redhat/Fedora uses `redhat-release`
   - Slackware  uses `slackware-release`
   - Gentoo uses `gentoo-release`

Debian's corresponding file is `/etc/debian_version`.  This file will also (somewhat misleadingly, but for a good reason) be present on Ubuntu systems, though.

1. Another file is `/etc/issue` which is used for machine identification and pre-login prompt can be used to determine current distribution information.
2. System information can be found in `/proc/version` too.

   ```
   cat /proc/version
   ```

Answer (score 3):

> One way would be to scan the output of uname -a to check for the right kernel version and architecture.

But one does not generally want to parse the output of such tools, because it's not elegant (it's considered a hack, so to say).

However, you can use the `uname()` function/syscall:

```
#include <sys/utsname.h>

struct utsname sysinfo;
if (uname(&sysinfo) < 0) {
    printf("Cannot determine OS\n");
    exit(-1);
}

printf("Operating system name: %s\n", sysinfo.sysname);
```

Comment: On my Ubuntu system sysinfo.sysname is "Linux" a bit bare IMHO

Answer (score 2):

You can use a library as a neutral to the operating system. A solution is [lsb](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb/lsb-41-release-notes)and your question became close to [using lsb question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337329/determine-linux-version-from-java).

Answer (score 0):

Afaik most Linux distributions also use `/etc/issue`. The text in it can ofcourse have been changed by the admin to show a different login message.

Sample from fedora:

```
Fedora release 17 (Beefy Miracle)
Kernel \r on an \m (\l)
```

Sample from ubuntu:

```
Ubuntu 11.04 \n \l
```