# Programmatically determine the distro I'm running

Tags: c++, linux

ALL,

I'm trying to see what is the Linux flavor I'm running my C++ program under.

I found [this answer on SO suggesting the uname program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292750/programmatically-determining-ubuntu-distribution-and-architecture) but one generally don't want to parse the output of some utility inside the C++ code.

Now I can do such test in configure, but I'm interested in what OS is user of my program have and not where I'm doing compilation which might be completely different (I personally love Gentoo, but no one can guarantee my customers will have it).

So is there any reliable way to determine from the C++ program the name of the Linux distro?

Comment: I don't see why your linked question is inadequate; among the answers, there's the `uname()` function and parsing various files under `/etc`, none of which constitute "parsing the output of some utility inside the C++ code".

Comment: What kind of API are you looking for as an alternative to the linked question? Note that there can be new linux distributions every day.

Comment: I think you are going to have to use a different method for each `OS`.

Comment: @congusbongus, I believe the comment to the "uname" answer says: "it gives 'Linux' instead of 'Ubuntu'", which is presumably correct.

Comment: @BillLynch, I'm looking for an API which can reliably determine if I'm running a specific *nix distro (mandriva, gentoo, red hat, ubuntu, solaris, aix, hp-ux, etc). I don't really care about "Android" one as it is JAVA.

Comment: Your best bet is to parse lsb_release file. It will work in most Linux distros.

Comment: "echo 'Congratulations. You aren't running Eunice'" - Larry Wall, inventor of Perl, in its configuration script. That was a huge pile of heuristics, few of which depended on what the OS said it was because they lie so often.

Comment: "[I] generally don't want to parse the output of some utility inside the C++ code."  Frankly, that's dumb.  Linux (like Unix, BSD, MacOS, et al) is *rich* in command-line tools where it makes *perfect* sense to use them (and parse the results).  Unfortunately, determining Linux distro isn't necessarily one of those instances. reading (and parsing) `/etc/lsb-release` (or, better, `/etc/*-release`) is arguably your best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing the top answer to this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/how-can-i-get-distribution-name-and-version-number-in-a-simple-shell-script on Unix Stack Exchange:

Slightly better than exec'ing a command and parsing it out would telling your code to parse the file /etc/lsb-release, which looks something this:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
```

The line DISTRIB_ID is the line with the distro name on it.  **Warning**, per the [lsb-release man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lsb_release), this line is optional. However, recent versions of many distros (including Mint, Ubuntu, Redhat, and yes, Gentoo) contain DISTRIB_ID in their /etc/lsb-release files.

Given these caveats, you may find parsing lsb-release works good enough for your purposes, although for widest coverage you'll have to bite the bullet and exec and parse the output of the associated utility `lsb_release`, as well as possibly falling back to other utilities.

Comment: Saying to use a shell script is not a C++ answer.

Comment: @Eugene - I'm recommending parsing a file, not using  shell script.  The post on Unix Stack Exchange was trying to solve the same problem in a shell script the OP to this question is trying to solve in C++.

Comment: @lreeder, how recent is "recent"?

Comment: @Igor - no idea.  It's probably more correct to say "the most current versions of many distros...".   I got the list above by searching the web for distro names with source files "/etc/lsb_release" containing the string "DISTRIB_ID".   AFAIK, there's no single reference listing distributions and their conformance to LSB.

Comment: `cat: /etc/lsb-release: No such file or directory` -- Don't think you would have any luck identifying my Fedora16 machine

Comment: @lreeder, this is exactly my point. The initial problem comes from the try to check if I'm running under Ubuntu Unity as it modifies too many things from official GTK+ distribution. But now I just wonder how to do that in general and do it reliably.

Comment: @Soren, I think the file name is "/etc/XXX-release", where "XXX" is changes based on the distribution. But this is still unreliable. ;-)